# Android Jetpack project How to show catogories of news from public api in get started screen and how to use it later in my project

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, newsapi

Im trying to develop a project in jetpack compose a news app. In the get started screen we will see all the different types of news categories that the public api offers . I dont know how to store the users selection of interests . how to use these selected interested topic later in the project to fetch only news according to the selected topic and to display in home screen feed.

I think its because of my poor selection of words i couldn't able to find appropriate guide on this problem from google search . thats why Im asking here please help if anyone knows anything about this. please share resources too for better understanding .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I dont know how to store the users selection of interests . how to use these selected interested topic later in the project to fetch only news according to the selected topic and to display in home screen feed.

There are several approaches to storing data on-device in android. You can look into [preferences datastore](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/datastore) where you would store values as key. You could also store data in a database using [room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room)

The android developers website has a whole section on data persistence. You can check it out [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data)